# Flow launch method

Tags: rest-api, release-update

I am new to SF and trying to verify the release update in our dev sandbox https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_release_update_user_context_via_rest_api.htm&type=5&release=242

Where in Setup or Workbench I can check if a Flow has been launched via REST Api and which context was it run?

I am trying to understand the before and after behavior of this update.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to verify that the Release Update was enabled

- `Setup | Release Update` - if enabled, it is enabled

To prove it works, create a Flow that does a Get Records on `Account` and an update on `Account`. Define the Flow as run in System Context. Activate Flow.

- Then, create a user with Profile `Minimum Access - Salesforce` plus a Permission Set with `API enabled` and `Run Flows`.
- Authenticate to SFDC with that user and then invoke the REST run flow URI.
- The flow should not find the Account nor update it as it will run in User Context.
- You can selectively add permissions to the permission set to verify that if given View All/Modify All to Account (or use sharing rules) the Flow will execute as expected.